# (Beamer) Numbering captions by section in beamer

Tags: beamer, floats, captions, numbering

I'm writing-up a lecture course in LaTeX with an essentially identical set of slides in `beamer`. I'd like to have the figure numbering in the `beamer` slides to match those of the lecture notes, for the sake of consistency in cross-referencing.

The lecture notes are written in the article document style (in particular there are no chapters), and have figures numbered by section (i.e. `\section`.`\figure`). Is there some simple preamble-trick or workaround that will change the way that the captions are produced in `beamer` to number them consistently with the lecture notes?

I'm trying to avoid having to write a new macro to use in the main body, since I'm compiling the notes and slides from the same set of source-files using `\input`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's actually very easy, though I had to read the manual for a while.  Add these lines to your preamble:

```
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
```

The first line uses another template for captions, one that inserts the figure's number.  Luckily this functionality is already built into beamer.

The second line declares that the `figure` counter is subordinate to the `section` counter, so resets for each new `\section` and labels figures 1.1, 1.2, ..., 2.1, 2.2, ....  This is built into LaTeX.

That's it!